# Datalist only displaying and serving 1st word

Tags: php, html

OK, Let's start again. The purpose of this code is to update a database table (db.aotm) comprising the club members who will be featured during the coming year as "The Artist of the Month". The first (html)table shows a list of members who gualify as Features Artists. Their names are hald in the $featuredArtist array.

Next, the $aotm array is populated with the current list of "month" and "member" held in the db.aotm table these are used as the default values of the form.
Then the datalist is populated with names from the $featuredArtist array.

The problem is that when the Form Input box is clicked the datalist box only shows the first name of each artist and any selection only enters the first name.
I have tried using a simple variable instead ogf th array in the datalist but the same happens if  $name = "John Smith"; then only "John" is displayed and entered into the input box. If I replace the soft datalist a hard coded datalist then it functions normally. So it seems tha any variable in the datalist only serves the first word.

My code is :

```
<?php
echo '<div class="dbrd"> 
$query = " SELECT id, status, fullname FROM members ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (bitN($row[status],2) == 1 && $row[id] > 20){
        $featuredArtist[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $featuredArtist[$i]['artist'] = $row['fullname'];
        $i++;
    }
}   

?>                      
<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="3">Featured Artists</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php                                   
            $j = 0; 
            while ($j < $i){
                echo " <tr><td>".$featuredArtist[$j]['artist']."</td>";
                $j++;
                echo " <td>".$featuredArtist[$j]['artist']."</td>";
                $j++;
                echo " <td>".$featuredArtist[$j]['artist']."</td></tr>";
                $j++;
            }
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <br />
</div>
<?php
$query = "SELECT id, artist FROM aotm";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$k = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $aotm[$k]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $aotm[$k]['artist'] = $row['artist'];
    $k++;
}
$l = 0;
echo '<datalist id = "artist">';
    while ($l < $i) {
        $artist = $featuredArtist[$l]['artist'];
        echo " <option value = ".$artist.">";
        $l++;
    }
?>                      
</datalist>

<form action = "" method = "POST">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Jan</td><td><input type = "text" list = "artist" name="1" size = "45" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sept</td><td><input list = "artist" type = "text" name="2" value = "<?php echo $aotm[1]['artist'];?>" size = "45" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type = "submit" name = "aotm" value = "Save" /></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are assigning $selected but never using it when you generate the html for your options.

Comment: I should have deleted that , it's a leftover from a previous idea using an option dropdown box but that didn't work either. Doesn't effect the result, still only get the firstname.I tried using a simple variable instead of the array but that's just the same.

Comment: Since the option value is `$featuredArtist[$l]['artist']` and there is no code shown creating that array, it is impossible to say. (Could also explain why `selected` didn't work). If you replace the option value with `$aotm[$l]['artist']` do you get the result you seek?

Comment: I have rewritten the post and included the complete code. Hope this helps

Comment: I still do not see where `$featuredArtist` is populated. Have you looked at the HTML using broswer dev tools? Does this generate valid HTML? Don't know what problem it might cause but this line `$aotm[$k][id] = $row[id];` is questionable since `id` is neither a variable nor a string literal.

Comment: Oops, I missed a bit out, full routine there now, sorry. I had spotted the missing quotes around "id" but it made no diffference and that variable is not being used yet. I came up with a workaround, `str_replace (" ", "&#32;",$featuredArtist[$l]['fullname']` that works fine. It would be nice to know if my code is wrong or if this a limitation with datalist. Thanks for your help. @ DinoCoderSaurus

Comment: Based on the `str_replace` solution, it is neither the code nor a limitation with datalist. It is how `members.fullname` is being stored in the database. You might want to have a look at the routine that populates `members`. It sounds like a real pain to have to remember that `fullname` contains an HTML space, not an ASCII space.

Comment: Um, see what you mean. `fullname` is stored as `"firstname lastname"` ie an ASCII space. I've not written the rewrite code yet but I guess a `str_replace("&#32;", " ",$featuredArtist[$l]['fullname'])` will put it all right. I'll check it out and report back

Comment: Mysql accepts `fullname` without using a `str_replace()` so it seems that `datalist` needs the space type changing, `@ DinoCoderSaurus`